# Adding to columns with paste in mutate_at

Tags: r

I have the following test data:

```
structure(list(testcode = structure(1:3, .Label = c("1", "20", 
"300"), class = "factor"), testname = structure(c(2L, 3L, 1L), .Label = c("Bed", 
"Book", "Car"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("testcode", "testname"
), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame")
```

I have a function that identifies a specific column name, then adds a leading zero to the variables in that column as a character. (All the columns are character). Since the column variables in the "code" column is of variable length, I thought it was easiest to use paste0 as `paste0("0",column_name)`.

The function is as follows:

```
library(dplyr)

fix_codes <- function(df) {
  code_column <- grep("code$", colnames(df), value = TRUE)

  df <- df %>%
    mutate_at(.vars = code_column, .funs = funs(paste0("0",code_column)))
  return(df)
}
```

However, paste0 does not seem to understand that I want to paste together the column that is specified by code_column, and not "code_column" itself, as it does now. How do I make paste0 recognize it correctly?

What I want to end up with:

```
testcode   testname
01         Book
020        Car
0300       Bed
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `.` instead to apply `paste` on actual values of selected columns

```
fix_codes <- function(df) {
   code_column <- grep("code$", colnames(df), value = TRUE)
   df <- df %>%
       mutate_at(.vars = code_column, .funs = funs(paste0("0",.)))
   return(df)
}

df

#  testcode testname
#1        1     Book
#2       20      Car
#3      300      Bed

fix_codes(df)
#  testcode testname
#1       01     Book
#2      020      Car
#3     0300      Bed
```

---

Also the equivalent base R approach using `lapply` would be where we select the columns directly

```
df[grep("code$", colnames(df))][] <- 
         lapply(df[grep("code$", colnames(df))], function(x) paste0("0", x))
```

Comment: Thank you! This works perfectly.

Would you say that the same approach works with `filter_at(.vars = code_column, .funs = funs(. %in% c("Book","Car")))`? It seems to throw an error

Comment: @Haakonkas because `code_column` does not have values `c("Book","Car")`. We have already excluded them, it is in `testname` column.

Comment: Sorry, I wrote wrong, I meant `filter_at(.vars = code_column, .funs = funs(. %in% c("01","020")))`

Comment: @Haakonkas There is no `.funs` parameter in `filter_at` we need to select `.vars_predicate` for it. `df %>%
  filter_at(.vars = code_column, .vars_predicate = any_vars(. %in% c("01","020")))`. Check explanation at `?filter_at` with examples there.

Comment: You could also use `vars(ends_with("code"))` in the function